# sql query to remove the backslashes in super datatype column in redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Redshift DB

- Table name: `t1`
- Column name : `c1`
- Datatype of column `c1` : `super`

Value in column c1:

```
"{\"xyz1\":\"\",\xyz2\":\"No\",\"zyx3\":\"RSR\"}"
```

I tried to remove the backslashes in super column by writing below SQL query.

```
UPDATE t1
SET c1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(c1::VARCHAR(max), '\\\\', '', 1)
WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL;
```

But it is not working.

Can you please tell me how to remove the backslashes in column `c1`?

Expected value in column c1 after query execution:

```
"{"xyz1":"","xyz2":"No","zyx3":"RSR"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here.  First the surrounding double quotes need to be removed.  You should be desiring the final value to be:

```
{"xyz1":"","xyz2":"No","zyx3":"RSR"}
```

and then this value needs to be ingested as a super using json_parse() function.

Next since you are seeing these surrounding double quotes I'm wondering if the column is actually a super or a super with just a string in it.  It doesn't seem like the original value was store correctly.  Likely this is the issue you are trying to fix.

I'd also recommend using REPLACE() rather than regexp as this is simpler and faster.  LTRIM() and RTRIM() can be used to remove the inclosing double quotes.  So I'd look to use something like (untested):

```
UPDATE t1
SET c1 = REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(c1::VARCHAR(max),'"'),'"'), '\\', '')
WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL;
```